# Is there a way to get the CQL query generated by pyspark code

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, cassandra

Is there a way to get the CQL code generated by pyspark script? I have noticed the explain the method and it does not give the CQL queries. Below code is something I was testing various modes with explain method.

```
groups = load_table(sql, "users")
groups = groups.select("id").where(groups.disabled == lit(0))
groups.explain(mode="simple")
```

Env info:
spark-cassendra-connector: 3.0.1 ,
pyspark: 3.1.2

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: @AlexOtt a script that took about 14 min on spark 2.4 is now (spark 3.1.x) taking 45 minutes. I was wondering if this is a CQL query issue

Comment: there could be multiple reasons for that. I don't remember that CQL part significantly changed for 3.x versions. Check that you don't have tasks failures - this happens sometimes that Spark overloads individual nodes and tasks are restarted